# How to install puppet-server on centos stream 9?

Tags: centos, puppet

I have done:

1. dnf -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm
2. dnf -y install https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet-release-el-9.noarch.rpm

But, it still can not find puppetserver:

```
[root@xxx ~]# dnf search puppetserver
Last metadata expiration check: 1:06:31 ago on Sun 20 Nov 2022 16:36:51 CST.
No matches found.
```

Answer (score 1):

EL9 is supported as a client OS since Puppet 7.14 (latest is 7.20), but it is not on [the list of supported server OSes for the latest Puppet (7.20.0)](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/server/install_from_packages.html#supported-operating-systems).  It is not then surprising that [the Puppet repository for EL9](https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet7/el/9/x86_64/index.html) does not presently contain RPMs for `puppetserver`, `puppetdb`, or other server-side Puppet components.

If you want to try anyway then you could attempt to use the EL8 packages on your EL9 system, but you would be on your own because, again, puppetserver is not presently supported on that OS.

I am inclined to think that EL9 support is planned, but I couldn't find a public roadmap, and I didn't see any relevant tickets in Puppet's issue tracker.  It might be worth your while to ask Puppet directly, or to ask in a more Puppet-specific community, such as the [puppet-users](https://groups.google.com/g/puppet-users) list.